# AngularJS: What is the best way to add JSON that ends with different ids inside $http.get()?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, scope

I am trying to display items from JSON, and it has an array of different ids at the end of url(/api/messages/:**messageId**). For example, /api/messages/12345  would be getting {"subject":"subject12345","body":"body12345","id":"12345"}.

My thought was that looping through data and adding it at the end of 'api/message/' would do the job. But I can't figure out how to define data before $http.get.

So what would be the best way to define data to make this work? Or is there any other way to solve this?

AngularJS code:

```
   var countryApp = angular.module('countryApp',[]);

   countryApp.controller('CountryCtrl', function($scope, $http){

  for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    var messageId = data[i].id;
    console.log(messageId);
   // data is undefined here
     }

   $http.get('/api/messages/' + messageId ).success(function(data){
   $scope.messages = data; 

  $scope.expand = function (message) {
  angular.forEach($scope.messages, function (currentItem){
  currentItem.showfull = currentItem == message && !currentItem.showfull;
        });
       };
      });
    });
```

JSON:

```
 // from api/messages/12345:
    {"subject":"subject12345","body":"body12345","id":"12345"}

//  from api/messages/123456789
    {"subject":"subject123456789","body":"body123456789","id":"123456789"}
// And so on...
```

Comment: What do you mean "define data before $http.get"? Data is the object passed back to you after the get call is made. You can't define it. It is defined for you. Can you clarify?

Comment: You need to call the for loop either via a function call in your $http success function or put the for loop in your succes function. That's all !

Comment: @Richard.Davenport, you're right, data is the object passed back to me after the get call. But in order to add each id at the end of JSON url I need it defined before $http.get(). My question was if I can call data before $http.get(), so I can loop it through different urls (data[i].id). Does it make this question clearer?

Comment: @user3492940, yes, I can definitely loop it inside $http success function, but I need it outside that function so I can add to the end of url at $https.get(). Any suggestion?

Comment: Then you would need to get the ids via another $http request before triggering the $http request in your example, or if you know the ids you can put them in a array and loop over that array(the hardcoded way).

Comment: @Amma, I'm not sure I see where you're getting data.length from. Unless it's defined, it will always be undefined.

Comment: @Richard.Davenport, data is coming from JSON data above. And I am trying to find the way to define it before $http.get().

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to do something like this:

```
$http.get('/api/messages/' + messageId).success(function(data) {
    for (obj in data) {
        data[obj] += messageId;
    }
    //do something with data.
});
```

Comment: Exactly. But messageId is undefined. How can it be defined before $http.get()?

Comment: Where does it come from? Is it a value the user inputs?

Comment: Data is referring to JSON, pulled from server api/messages. I need to add different ids at the end of url to get to different pages.

Comment: You want to modify every single JSON object this way? If that's the case, you need to give $http every single URL and iterate through them, or do this on the backend.

Comment: I am not modifying JSON object, but just adding unique id to the end of url that is called inside $http.get() so it can pull the right JSON, just like ones I've included above. I know I have to iterate data[i], but can't figure out how to define it so it works out inside $http.get(). Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I'm really confused by what exactly you are asking. I think you need to be a little more explicit, but is this anything close to what you're wanting?

```js
var countryApp = angular.module('countryApp', []);
countryApp.controller('CountryCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  var data = [{
    "subject": "subject12345",
    "body": "body12345",
    "id": "12345"
  }, {
    "subject": "subject123456789",
    "body": "body123456789",
    "id": "123456789"
  }];

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var messageId = data[i].id;
    console.log(messageId);

    $http.get('/api/messages/' + messageId).success(function(data) {
      $scope.messages = data;

      $scope.expand = function(message) {
        angular.forEach($scope.messages, function(currentItem) {
          currentItem.showfull = currentItem == message && !currentItem.showfull;
        });
      };
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="countryApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="CountryCtrl">
  Loading...
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What you did is correct, except JSON data is located in server and fetched through NodeJS with $http.get() instead of being inside controller (which would be solved with your answer). The whole issue is that each JSON has to be fetched outside of $http.get(), and I'm not quite sure how to define 'data' in this scenario to loop through them. Does this make the issue more clear?